# What can I do to stop my eyes from drying out when I'm driving?

Tags: temperature, car, comfort

When I'm driving in hot weather I use the air conditioning to keep cool. This keeps most of me comfortable, but it dries out my eyes no matter where I point the blowers. I then have to turn the air conditioning off since vision is quite important when driving but then I get too hot and the cycle starts again!

> What can I do to keep my vision clear, but stay at a comfortable temperature?

Comment: I have a similar problem in cold weather when running the heat.

Comment: I really feel like some of these are quite contrived in the interest of populating the beta... am i wrong?

Comment: This is a legit one for me

Comment: One issue is that people tend to blink less often when they are concentrating, or not looking around much. But, who does those things while *driving*? Remind yourself to blink more. Blinking also resets your self-awareness which helps with situational awareness (Default Processing Network).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Stay hydrated before you go -- this can only help. (But not so hydrated that you have to stop to do your... er, business.)
2. Stop at a rest area and sit with your eyes closed for a while.
3. (I've done this, but it may not be a good idea) Close one eye at a time for short periods (<3 sec.) when you are the only car around. (i.e., you're not merging on the highway or in heavy traffic.)
4. Wear glasses (if you don't already).
5. Use eyedrops that are made to keep your eyes hydrated.

Comment: 1 isn't a good idea as I'll just end up stopping more than I'd like to urinate, but 4 sounds like a good idea

Comment: Actually #1 is the most important here. Especially considering that up to 75% of Americans (in other countries its probably lower, but still substantially high) are chronically dehydrated. This of course affects all forms of  moisture, especially the non-critical ones such as tears.

Comment: To avoid having to stop often, your best bet would be to sip slowly and often. That way the moisture will be absorbed throughout your body (and eyes), and not go straight to your bladder.

Comment: I read that the body can only process about 1 cup / 8 ounces / half pint / 250 ml / 1/4 liter at a time. The rest goes out fairly quickly, so I concur with @AviD.

Answer (score 9):

Get yourself a set of sunglasses of which the actual lenses can be replaced. Popular low-cost sets have 3 different colors: black, orange and transparent. The black blocks 90% of the light, the orange about 40-50% and the transparent 10%. That 10% is negligible for sight, but it does keep the dry air away.

I usually wear them while biking, which seems like a comparable situation.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, I think.

[image: Driving Goggles]

Comment: please expand on the answer. Also, pointing to a product designed to solve the problem isn't a lifehack...it is simply common sense

Comment: @Phlume Considering [how accepted](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/239/what-are-some-waking-up-hacks-for-non-morning-person/246#246) [products are](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/393/how-can-i-clean-sticky-juice-off-my-hands-when-outside/394#394) [elsewhere on the site](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/11/182), I don't see how products *aren't* lifehacks.

Comment: It seems problematic for the site if certain answers are deemed unacceptable if they're not "lifehacky enough".

Comment: Goggles also keep bugs and dust out of your eyes. Gloves are good idea. Hat keeps your head warmer, which improves thinking, especially when A/C is on. Sometimes most of the cold air seems to hit the top of my head!