# How can I clean sticky juice off my hands when outside?

Tags: food, cleaning

Sometimes, I'm outside working or whatever, not near a water faucet. I work in some orchards, and sometimes I eat a fruit, which (of course) is very sticky. I usually wipe them off soon after they get wet, so it doesn't start drying on, but I always come back at the end of the day with sticky hands, and sometimes tools.

How can I quickly clean off after getting sugary juice on my hands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I eat an apple without getting sticky?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/187/how-can-i-eat-an-apple-without-getting-sticky)

Comment: @Tim No, that question asks how to eat without getting sticky, this one asks what to do when sticky. :)

Comment: Very similar :/ I'm not convinced about retracting it. I'll see if other close too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop my fingers getting sticky when eating?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1827/how-can-i-stop-my-fingers-getting-sticky-when-eating)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, as it talks about cleaning more and not eating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way would be to find some type of water, whether it's a puddle, a stream, bottled water, licking your hands, or something else near you.

If that's not an option, you could try crushing up moist leaves or grass. In my experience it provides enough moisture to remove a good bit of the stickiness when combined with rubbing. Of course, then your hands will smell like plants...

Another method my friend mentioned to me is to rub dirty/sand into your hands. It will stick to the sticky juice and you won't have to deal with the stickiness any longer. You might be able to rub some of the dirt off, bringing some stickiness with it as well.

Comment: If it is the evening or morning, the dew will have fallen and is great. If you don't rub too hard, the grass won't smell that much.

Comment: Everybody's got a tongue. Lick your fingers. I did it just now after eating my apple.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to fruit...You can try the juice/oil from a lemon or orange peel/skin It's a mild solvent and if you rub on your hands would cut that stickiness. Squeeze/press/Rub the peel into your hands to get the oil out. Mix with a little water to help spread it which may help.

Answer (score 0):

Use of gloves will keep your skin off from contact of juicy liquid of fruits. 
[image]

Comment: Or start wearing them after eating your sticky fruit, your hands will stay sticky but your tools will stay clean.

Answer (score 0):

*Best Way to get rid of sticky hands:*

**CARRY SOAP PAPER ALONG WITH YOU! Always**;

So that wherever you get water you can just rinse-off the soap from hands and they are clean and you are good to go!